# Created a method that returns a true value is the object is 5+ years old

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I want to create a method which returns a Boolean value. It should return true if the sale is over 5 years old or older and false if the sale is under 5 years.

I have given it an attempt but I cannot seem to get it work. If anyone can think over a more efficient way of completing this I am open to a different direction.

I have tried the below but the method continue to error out no matter what I change. Google has not been helpful either as the method is so specific.

the method is called *isSaleOld()* (Go to the bottom of the code)

Thank you for any help in advance. Code is below for the whole project.

```
public class Sale
{
// instance variables
private String company;
private String yearBought;
private int saleValue;
private Seller seller;

public Sale(String aCompany, String aYear, int aValue, 
Seller theSeller)
{
  this.company = aCompany;
  this.yearBought = aYear;
  this.saleValue = aValue;
  this.seller = theSeller;
}

public void setSellersName(String aName)
{
  this.seller.setName(aName);
}

public void setSaleValue(int aValue)
{
  this.saleValue = aValue;
}

public void setyearBought(String aYear)
{
  this.yearBought = aYear;
}

public void setCompany(String aCompany)
{
  this.company = aCompany;
}

public int getSaleValue()
{
  return this.saleValue;
}

public boolean isApprovalRequired()
{
  return this.getSaleValue() >=10000;
}

public String getYearBought()
{
  return this.yearBought;
}

public void isSaleOld(String[] args)
{
  yearBought = getYearBought("2020");

  boolean after = yearBought.after(yearBought);
}
}
```

Comment: Use an object which represents a date (and optionally time) rather than `String`. Ideally, you'd use something from the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) API added in Java 8. Then use the methods of that API to test if the sale is 5+ years old.

Comment: For example: `localSellDate.compareTo(LocalDate.now().minusYears(5)) <= 0`. That makes use of `LocalDate`. If you need offset information, use `OffsetDateTime`. If you need timezone information, use `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Sale {

    private int yearBought;

    public void sale(int year) {
        setYearBought(year);
    }

    private int getYearBought() {
        return this.yearBought;
    }

    private void setYearBought(int year) {
        this.yearBought = year;
    }

    public boolean isSaleOld() {
        int now = LocalDateTime.now().getYear();
        int yearBought = getYearBought();
        if (now - yearBought > 5) {
            System.out.println("Yes, older than 5 years");
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("No, less than 5 years old");
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sale sale = new Sale();
        Sale sale2 = new Sale();

        sale.sale(2010);
        sale2.sale(2020);

        sale.isSaleOld();
        sale2.isSaleOld();

    }
```